# Azure log analytics timechart with multiple dimensions

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

In the [Azure new log analytics query platform](https://docs.loganalytics.io/index) you can query for performance counters and summarize them to finally create a nice graph.

Following the [multiple dimensions documentation example](https://docs.loganalytics.io/docs/Learn/Tutorials/Charts-and-diagrams#multiple-dimensions) it says

> Multiple expressions in the by clause creates multiple rows, one for
>   each combination of values.

**I want to query their sample database for networks bytes Send and Received per each computer**. Starting with [this query](https://portal.loganalytics.io/demo?q=H4sIAAAAAAAAA1WOuwqDQBREe79iEAIKW2jAIoVpUqQLFpJ%2B1YkK7m64u%2BZFPj4PQsB6zjlMRTlFT1wHClGPhntaig7ssIXuXZJ3Kf7Azs02UA7aEGWJeIVKXEvvnXzl%2BIP62Rgt44PQlz75KUc9zUwVzpSWNowT%2FWJSKDKFTZECzR3NaJPFGYV8SN9t3gJth3oQ%2BsFNHUqss%2BgF6bL7icUAAAA%3D) it should be something like

`Perf
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
| where (CounterName == "Bytes Received/sec" or CounterName == "Bytes Sent/sec")
| summarize avg(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), Computer, CounterName
| extend Threshold = 20
| render timechart`

The problem is that **Send and Received bytes gets grouped in the graph at computer level**.

How can multiple dimensions be represented as stated in the documentation so that I have *Computer X Bytes Send* and *Computer X Bytes Received* instead of them grouped together witch doesn't make any sense?

[image: Bytes send and received get mixed in the graph]

Not to mention that in the previous version this was working as expected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I though that if multiple dimensions are not really accepted a string concatenation would do the trick. A bit hackish in my opinion but it did.

```
Perf
| where (CounterName == "Bytes Received/sec" or CounterName == "Bytes Sent/sec") and InstanceName matches regex "^Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter.*$"
| summarize avg(CounterValue) by strcat(Computer, " ", CounterName), bin(TimeGenerated, 10s)
| render timechart
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is this

```
let RuntimeID = CosmosThroughput_CL 
| where MetricName_s == "ProvisionedThroughput" and TimeGenerated between (ago(2h) .. ago(1h))
| order by TimeGenerated desc  
| top 1 by TimeGenerated
| distinct RuntimeID_g;
CosmosThroughput_CL 
| where MetricName_s == "ProvisionedThroughput" and RuntimeID_g in (RuntimeID)
| project Resource = toupper(Resource), Value = Throughput_d, Container = Container_s, Database = Database_s, MetricName = "Provisioned"
| union 
    (
        AzureDiagnostics 
        | where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.DOCUMENTDB" and Category == "PartitionKeyRUConsumption"
        | where TimeGenerated between (ago(1d) .. ago(1d-1h))
        | summarize Value = sum(todouble(requestCharge_s)) by Resource, databaseName_s, collectionName_s
        | project Resource, Container = collectionName_s, Database = databaseName_s, Value, MetricName = "HourlyUsage"
    ) 
| union 
    ( 
        AzureDiagnostics 
        | where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.DOCUMENTDB" and Category == "PartitionKeyRUConsumption"
        | where TimeGenerated between (ago(1d) .. ago(1d-1h))
        | summarize Value = sum(todouble(requestCharge_s)/3600) by Resource, databaseName_s, collectionName_s
        | project Resource, Container = collectionName_s, Database = databaseName_s, Value, MetricName = "RUs"
    )
| project Resource, Database, Container, Value, MetricName
```

The important part is to `project` the same column names. `Value` holds the different values from each table. Second `union` helps me project another value from the same table.